# Unclear use of Storage

Tags: vapor

How do I use Storage in Vapor 4?

I tried the following:

```
if let someValue = req.storage.get(theKey) as? String {
    // do something
} else {
    req.storage.set(theKey, to: "Some Value")
}
```

However I get the following Errors:

```
error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    if let original: String = req.storage.get(theKey) {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    req.storage.set(theKey, to: "Some Value")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also did not find any documentation on this topic.

Comment: Try to look into sources of dependencies of your project, you will find a lot of best practices.

Comment: @imike example please - If there where lots of best practices, they where easy to find, right?

Comment: https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/FCM/blob/6f85590038bcdd661382b82ecd7c6bb57e073e0c/Sources/FCM/FCM.swift#L90

Comment: This assumes there is exactly 1 key which is known. I need to set an arbitrary key.

Comment: I think you could just implement your own storage by copying Vapor's implementation which is 80 lines only and change their `[ObjectIdentifier: AnyStorageValue]` dictionary to desired `[String: AnyStorageValue]`

Answer (score 0):

The input key is actually a Protocol use must implement. If you want to see examples of how Store is used, do like @imike says and look for usages of the Storage class.

Comment: So I make String conform to that protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Storage is not string based key object storage. You have to declare a `struct` conforming to `StorageKey`, implement the `typealias` Value representing the object type you want to store.

If you need to store a string let's take this example :

```swift
struct MyStringKey: StorageKey {
     typealias Value = String
}

...

request.storage.set(MyStringKey.self, to: "my string")
var myString: String? = request.storage.get(MyStringKey.self)
```

Comment: I think Redis is the preferred way to store these kinds of cache variables.

Comment: Yes probably bu it can be done that way to (even if in case of string key base value it's not optimal...)

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible for the Key to be any arbitrary String. The key must be predefined.